# Can I change current directory to parent directory using PHP __DIR__ constant?

Tags: php, file-upload, path, dir, magic-constants

I am using PHP magic constant to move uploaded file to a new location, and the upload handler file location is inside "`_inc`" file inside the main application folder like this:

> "path/tasksapp/_inc/upload_handelr.php"

So; when I use `__DIR__` I get the path where the upload hander is exist:

> "path/tasksapp/_inc/"

While the new location for uploaded file should be:

> "path/tasksapp/uploads"

Is there's any option or attribute I can use with `__DIR__` constant so I can change current directory to parent directory:

change:

> "path/tasksapp/_inc/"

to be:

> "path/tasksapp/"

Comment: `__DIR__/../uploads/`

Comment: Do you have a main file in `path/tasksapp/` that includes/requires `upload_handler.php`???

Comment: @AbraCadaver no it's ajax upload handler file via js

Comment: @AbraCadaver that not working '__DIR__/../uploads/' !

Comment: It would be `__DIR__ . '/../uploads/'`. But might I suggest using a singleton to store this configuration property (or something similar) so that your code doesn't care (or even know!) where it's located and how that is relative to files that it needs to move.

Comment: @AbraCadaver it's not working, it gives "/tasksapp/_inc/../uploads/" !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend `dirname(__DIR__)`:

- it's portable (works on Windows where `a/b/../c` is not allowed)
- it's readable

Comment: Inside `upload_handelr.php` something like `$dir=dirname(__DIR__)` would create a variable pointing to the upload directory. Append the filename use `move_uploaded_file()`